# Not getting Social Token when using SignIn with Slack

Tags: python, django, slack, django-allauth

I am using `django-allauth==0.61.1`. I have added settings for Slack. I can successfully Signup/Login on my web app using the SignIn with Slack. I get the `email`, `slack_user_id`, and `username` from Slack. But I don't get any `social_token` for that user.

The user will be using my Slack app with some commands. I need the token with an expiry date to determine whether the user is logged or logged out.

I have checked the OAuth Scopes. I have the following User Token Scopes:

- `email`
- `openid`
- `profile`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I haven't added code, as I am only using functionality as provided by `django-allauth`. I just added slack credentials to the `social_applications` table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by setting `SOCIALACCOUNT_STORE_TOKENS = True` in `settings.py` file of my django project